# get coordinates of marker relative to device screen intstead of mapcontainer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to get the coordinates of marker in map. I am getting the coordinates relative to mapcontainer.I am using the below code.

```
Projection projection = map.getProjection();

LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();

Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(markerLocation);
```

But i want the coordinates relative to entire device screen.

Comment: Your question is wrong. Market position is in latitude and longitude while screen is in px/dp. It is not possible what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need this? You have to rethink your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this. but this may be a solution. 
Add an overlay of a relative or linear layout on your mapfragment with aplha = 0.
get the screen size. 
`Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();`
`Point mScreenSize = new Point();`
`mDisplay.getSize(mScreenSize);`
`int width = mScreenSize.x;`
`int height = mScreenSize.y;`

on the onTouchListner of the layout.
`event.getRawX() and getRawY()` 
will give you the coordinates of the screen.